# shared / exclusive locking scheme and strict two-phase locking protocol

Tags: database, concurrency, locking

[exam question]Given a key:

```
S: r3(X); r1(Y); w3(Z); w3(X); w1(Z); w1(X); r2(X); w2(Z); w2(Y); r1(X);
```

and also

```
T1: r1(Y); w1(Z); w1(X); r1(X); 
T2: r2(X); w2(Z); w2(Y); 
T3: r3(X); w3(Z); w3(X);
```

Indicate after each  operation which locks are there. I really dont understand it and I need your help. thank you.

this is the answer: but I have no idea how its done.

[image]

time stamp ordering for this question:

[image]

Comment: You may ask your examiner?

Comment: @jruizaranguren there no time for that otherwise I would have, they wont asnwer questions 2 days before the exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: *This should be a comment, but I don't have reputation for it*

I don't think you should be asking for help about homework, though I can point that if **S** is the sequence of operations (it looks like it is) then the answer is pretty straighforward.

EDIT:

On chapter 16, Section 4, Figure 16.15 of Distributed Systems: Concepts and Design 5th edition ([link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Distributed-Systems-George-Coulouris/dp/0273760599/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1429183582&sr=8-1&keywords=distributed+systems+concepts+and+design)) you have the lock compatibility table.
Also, Figure 16.16 has everything you need to know to execute the 2PL.

As for the commits (the c1, c2, c3), you just need to look at the last operation of each transaction.

Thus, first build the table with the operations and the commit events and then, for each object (X, Y, Z) determine who has the locks by using the references I just gave you.

Comment: its not a homework its an exam question and I am trying to understand it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I hope it helps enough. And, that book is a great reference for starting on distributed systems.

Comment: @ Duarte Patrício thank you, i try to read it in a litle time I have, do you know also about how the basic timeste,p redering is done??

Comment: @David You mean timestamp ordering?

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to understand these two for a while but I cant. I think I understand how 2pl is done now, but I still dont see how you can move r1 to the next transaction after c3. and yes I meant timestamp ordering. with the same S.

Comment: R1 is not moved, nothing is moved. Everything works as a "registry" of the current transactions. Having r1 after c3 on Y means that, even though T3 ended T1 still has a read lock on Y. That is obvious because T1 never ended (it commits only at the end).When transactions commit they only realease their locks. As for timestamp ordering, chapter 16.6, Figure 16.29 and 16.30 of the same book show every rule you need to know. Also, google has lots of links to search for. Mind that timestamps are assigned at the beggining of each T. For your case, T3 < T1 < T2.

Comment: thanks alot for your help I do understand 2PL now much better than before, I can actually sovle the problem now, But I still dont get the TS ordering, its very confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75402/discussion-between-duarte-patricio-and-david).

Comment: I am here, waiting for you on the chat.

Comment: I cant send u any more messages it gives me an unkown error has accrued.